# EditText setError() delete the drawable right

Tags: android

I have EditText 
in it XML written: `android:drawableRight="@drawable/promotion_create_promotion_plus_icn"`

when `setError("sss")` the `drawableRight` change.

I want when `setError(null)` the `drawableRight` return to be `drawable/promotion_create_promotion_plus_icn`

the XML:

`<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/create_benefit_add_titale"
                    style="@style/promotion_create_promotion_add_title_bcg"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/promotion_create_promotion_plus_icn"
                    android:hint="@string/create_benefit_add_titale" />`

in java:

`@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
((EditText) getCurrentFocus()).setError(null);
}`

who can help me?

Comment: Paste the whole code here (including the XML of the EditText, then we'll see what can be done.

Comment: i didn't get your question?? is drawable right is missing or you want to dismiss it ?? give me some clarity..

Comment: Did you try my answer? Please do and let me know if it helped you.

Comment: This is a good answer but it does not suit me.   Because I end a lot of EditText's and each has its own image

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `setError(null)` clears also the icon.
To restore the original one, add it [programmatically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  EditText edit = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
  edit.setError(null);
  edit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.promotion_create_promotion_plus_icn, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap `EditText` with a `TextInputLayout` and set error for `textInputLayout` instead of `editText`